# Counterexample of Split exact Sequences

Tags: commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

I read "Undergraduate Commutative Algebra By Miles Reid".

I don't understand this description、

"Whether an exact sequence is split or not on what ring it is considered over.

For example,$k $ is field.

$0 \rightarrow (x) \rightarrow k[x] \rightarrow k \rightarrow 0   $
   is split over  $k$ but not over $k[x]$ ".

I guess if over $k$,$k[x]=(x) \oplus k$ and its bases of vector space is $x $ and $1$.

But if over $k[x]$, I can't construct counterexample morphism.

Please show me a not split example.

Comment: A vector space basis of $(x)$ looks like $\{x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$. That ideal is a cyclic $k[x]$-module, though.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite right.  Over $k$, the sequence splits, but a basis for $k$ is $1$ while a basis for $(x)$ is $\{x,x^2,x^3, \dots\}$.

There are many ways to see why the sequence does not split over $k[x]$. For instance, If the sequence were to split, then we would have $k[x] \cong (x) \oplus k$ as $R$-modules. In particular, this would mean $k[x]$ contains a nonzero element annihilated by $x$, which is not the case.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I misunderstand over $k$.$k[x]$ contains a nonzero element annihilated by x is mean polynomial like $f(x)=x+a$?

Comment: @batayan As an $R$-module, $k \cong R/(x)$; indeed, the last map in the sequence you wrote down is the natural projection $R \to R/(x)$. In particular, this means every element of $k$ is annihilated by $x$, that is, $xr=0$ for all $r \in k$. Now if $R \cong (x) \oplus k$ as $R$-modules, then an element like $(0,r)$ (with $r \ne 0$) inside $(x) \oplus k$ is annihilated by $x$.  But $R$ is a domain, so no such element can exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got it

Answer (score 0):

Some easy example of an exact sequence that does not split... Consider the following abelian groups as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules... Then the followin sequence is exact,
$$
  0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow\mathbb{Z_2}\rightarrow0
$$
where the morphism $\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_4$ *is just inclusion* and the next arrow, $\mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_2$ is reduction modulo $4$. Clearly, this sequence doesn't split! If it splits, then $\mathbb{Z}_4\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ but the right-hand side is not a cyclic group.

(By "*is just inclusion*" I mean of course $0\mapsto0$ and $1\mapsto2$.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I got it.